# Linkedin API does not return email address in Django 2.0

Tags: python, django, api, linkedin-api

Here is the test code:

**Step #1:** Request Auth Code

```
args_str = urlencode({
        'response_type' : 'code',
        'client_id' : '<app client id>',
        'scope' : 'r_emailaddress r_basicprofile',
        'state' : '<my state id>',
        'redirect_uri' : '<app redirect url>'
        })
url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization'
return redirect(url +  '?' + args_str)
```

**Step #2** Handle call back

**Step #3**  Get access token

**Step #4** Get data from linkedin using access token

```
def get_linkedin_data(request, access_token):

api_endpoint_profile = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~'
access_token = access_token

headers = {}
headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + access_token
headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0'
headers['x-li-format'] = 'json'

values = {
        'format' : 'json'
}

data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
data = data.encode('ascii')

url_request = urllib.request.Request(api_endpoint_profile, data=data, headers=headers, method='GET')
url_response = urllib.request.urlopen(url_request)

response_data_profile = json.loads(url_response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

The response_data_profile variable contains basic profile data only but not the email address.

What am i missing here?

Note:

1. App created in Linkedin developer account with r_basicprofile and r_emailaddress scopes selected
2. Permission granted to scopes basicprofile and emailaddress When api tries to get linked data

Comment: It looks like you can't get email addresses from the `v1/people` endpoint. Have a look at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2/people/primary-contact-api#email.

Comment: I get the below error when i call v2 api  - "/v2/clientAwareMemberHandles?q=members&projection=(elements*(primary,type,handle~))" Error: {
    "serviceErrorCode": 100,
    "message": "Not enough permissions to access: GET-members /clientAwareMemberHandles",
    "status": 403
}